# How many non-isomorphic graphs with n vertices and m edges are there?

Tags: graph-theory

Could someone tell me how to find the number of all non-isomorphic graphs with $m$ vertices and $n$ edges.
(The graph is simple, undirected graph)

In my particular problem, $m =20, n=180$

Attempt at solution:

1. Find the total possible number of edges (so that every vertex is connected to every other one)
   $k = n(n-1)/2 = 20\cdot19/2 = 190$
2. Find the number of all possible graphs:
   $s = C(n,k) = C(190, 180) = 13278694407181203$

Now, I'm stuck because a huge portion of the above number represents isomorphic graphs, and I have no idea how to find all those that are non-isomorphic...

Comment: Hint: consider the complements of your graphs.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I still don't get it, because I don't really see how you can consider every single complement. I mean, the number is huge...

Comment: How many edges will the complements have?  If two complements are isomorphic, what can you say about the two original graphs?  Or, if the two complements are not isomorphic?

Comment: For each graph, the complement to this graph is going to have 10 edges (190-180). I see what you are trying to say. I have to figure out how many non-isomorphic graphs with 20 vertices and 10 edges there are, right?

Comment: I might be wrong, but a vertex cannot be connected "to 180 vertices". There are a total of 20 vertices, so each one can only be connected to at most 20-1 = 19. Also, the complete graph of 20 vertices will have 190 edges. Our graph has 180 edges. So, when we build a complement, we remove those 180, and add extra 10 that were not present in our original graph. So, it's 190 -180. I don't really see where the -1 comes from. Anyhow, you gave me an incredibly valuable insight into solving this problem. If you consider copying your +1 comment as a standalone answer, I'll gladly accept it:)!

Comment: @user825089 Sorry, wasn't thinking straight... yes, 10 edges.

Comment: So you've reduced it to finding the number of (isomorphism classes of) graphs on 20 vertices and 10 edges - now what? I think it's still a formidable problem, especially if you try to do it by hand. The answer exceeds 4500.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson Yes, I thought something was wrong too. That's why I re-asked today and it turns out I was given the incorrect data. It's not 180, but 188 edges. So, complements will have 2 edges and 20 vertices. Therefore, we have 2 non-isomorphic graphs (one, when edges are connected and the other when they are not).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First off, let me say that you can find the answer to this question in Sage using the nauty generator.  If you're going to be a serious graph theory student, Sage could be very helpful.

```
count = 0
for g in graphs.nauty_geng("20 180:180"):
    count = count+1
print count
```

The answer is 4613.  But, this isn't easy to see without a computer program.

At this point, perhaps it would be good to start by thinking in terms of of the number of *connected* graphs with at most 10 edges.  Then, all the graphs you are looking for will be unions of these.  You should be able to figure out these smaller cases.  If any are too hard for you, these are more likely to be in some table somewhere, so you can look them up.

Connected graphs of order n and k edges is:

```
n = 1, k = 0: 1
n = 2, k = 1: 1
n = 3, k = 2: 1
n = 3, k = 3: 1
n = 4, k = 3: 2
n = 4, k = 4: 2
n = 4, k = 5: 1
n = 4, k = 6: 1
n = 5, k = 4: 3
n = 5, k = 5: 5
n = 5, k = 6: 5
n = 5, k = 7: 4
n = 5, k = 8: 2
n = 5, k = 9: 1
n = 5, k = 10: 1
.
.
.
n = 10, k = 9: 106
n = 10, k = 10: 657
n = 11, k = 10: 235
```

I used Sage for the last 3, I admit.  But, I do know that the Atlas of Graphs contains all of these except for the last one, on P7.

Comment: I tried your solution after installing Sage, but with n = 50 and k = 180. The computation never seem to end, is this due to the too-large number of solutions?

If so, is there a way to find the number of non-isomorphic, connected graphs with n = 50 and k = 180?