# Calculating number of connected graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I want to calculate the number of connected graphs with `n` vertices. There is no other constraints like loop etc.

I am unable to think a general method for the same.

Any help appreciated.

[EDIT] I am looking something on lines of a general formula using combinatorics rather than the counting approach.

[EDIT 2]
**Restating the question:** I want to calculate the number of connected graphs with `n` vertices.

Comment: What do you mean with "no constraints like loop"? Loops are not allowed? Or loops are not excluded?

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112954/how-many-non-isomorphic-graphs-with-n-vertices-and-m-edges-are-there).

Comment: @Hegen As I said "no other constraints like loop" i.e. graphs with  loops are to be included.

Comment: Included?!  Then there's an infinite number of non-isomorphic (connected) graphs on 1 vertex:  For any $k \geq 0$, add $k$ loops to the vertex.  Are you adding a restriction that there's at most one loop on each vertex?  Also, are the graphs labelled or unlabelled?  The difference between labelled and unlabelled totally changes graphical enumeration questions.  May I suggest adding a table of what graphs are counted for $n \in \{1,2,3\}$ to your question?  It might be easier to understand what you're asking then.

Comment: @DouglasS.Stones I think what I edited for clarification is creating doubts. Please see the edit. I think it should be clear now what I want to do.

Comment: Here are some of the possible answers to the question "the number of connected graphs with n vertices": 1. [unlabelled connected simple graphs](http://oeis.org/A001349), 2. [labelled connected simple graphs](http://oeis.org/A001187), 3. [unlabelled connected simple graphs with at most one loop per node](http://oeis.org/A054921), 4. [labelled connected simple graphs with at most one loop per node](http://oeis.org/A062740).  If you include a table of the graphs for $n \in \{1,2,3\}$ we could probably deduce which version you mean.

Answer (score 2):

See enumerations at [OEIS](http://oeis.org/) or at [MathWorld Connected Graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConnectedGraph.html).