# How many non-isomorphic, connected graphs are there on $n$ vertices with $k$ edges?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm a non-mathematician working with applied graph theoretic tools. I need to figure out how many possible graphs exist for a problem of mine (in a graph structure optimization problem, quickly said).

In essence, my question is: how many non-isomorphic, connected graphs are there on $n$ vertices with $k$ edges?

Where, in my case, $n=50$ and $k=180$.

I had a hard time finding a straight forward answer to this question (other than iterating through a catalog of graphs, where $n$ is usually pretty small). Is there any way to compute such answer?

Thanks!

Comment: See http://oeis.org/A008406 and the references given there.

Comment: In short, it is not easy, and you might have to enumerate them.

See : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpleGraph.html

"There appears to be no standard term for a simple graph on n edges"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How many non-isomorphic graphs with n vertices and m edges are there?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112954/how-many-non-isomorphic-graphs-with-n-vertices-and-m-edges-are-there)

Comment: @AustinMohr I saw this question and tried the given solution, but n = 50 seems too much for sage to compute.

Comment: Thanks @manuellafond, I'm giving up on the idea of quickly getting an answer then :) Thanks everyone for help and insight!