# Number of different graphs

Tags: graph-theory

How many different graphs exist with $n$ vertices? 
$$$$
And how many with $n$ vertices and $k$ edges? $(0 \leq k \leq n)$

$$$$
For example the different graphs with $3$ vertices are:
[image]

Comment: Are you looking at graphs up to isomorphism or just the actual number of graphs?

Comment: You need to specify what you mean by "different".  [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112954/how-many-non-isomorphic-graphs-with-n-vertices-and-m-edges-are-there?lq=1) may be what you want.

Comment: @SiddharthVenkatesh I am just looking at the actual number of graphs.

Comment: @Goos I edited my post, I gave an example..

Comment: Then this should just be combinatorial data. For $n$ vertices and $k$ edges its just a matter of choosing $k$ distinct pairs of vertices amongst $n$ vertices. Then, to find the total number of graphs, you add up the values you got for individual $k$ from $k = 0$ to $k = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}.$

Comment: @SiddharthVenkatesh So you mean the total number of different graphs with $n$ vertices and $k$ edges is: $$\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}{\binom{n}{k}}$$??

Comment: No. what I mean is, suppose the total number of graphs with $n$ vertices and $k$ edges is $N(k)$. Then, the total number of graphs with $n$ vertices is 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}} N(k).$$
To figure out how many graphs are there with $n$ vertices and $k$ edges is just a matter of figuring out who many ways you can assign $k$ edges to a collection of $n$ vertices. Since each edge is determined by its two distinct vertices (I'm assuming you aren't allowing loops based on your example), this is a purely combinatorial problem.

Comment: @SiddharthVenkatesh What is $N(k)$ equal to??

Comment: It's just a label I'm using to denote the number of graphs with $n$ vertices and $k$ edges. I've given you a hint about how to calculate that in the paragraph after.

Answer (score 1):

There are ${n \choose 2}$ "slots" for the edges to go in.  Each of these "slots" can either have an edge, or not an edge.  So there are $2$ choices for each slot, which means the total number of graphs on $n$ distinct vertices is
$$
2^{n \choose 2}.
$$

To find the number of graphs with exactly $k$ edges, you just need to pick $k$ slots out of the ${n \choose 2}$ slots available.

Comment: Could you explain me how you found that there are $\binom{n}{2}$ "slots" for the edges to go in??

Comment: @MaryStar There are $n$ vertices.  If there is an edge in the graph, it has to go between some particular pair of two vertices.  So the number of slots is the number of possible pairs of vertices.  And there are ${n \choose 2}$ ways to pick a pair of vertices.

Comment: Aha! I got it! As regards the number of graphs with exactly $k$ edges,do you mean that it is $k \cdot \binom{n}{2}$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar  Not quite.  How many ways are there to pick $k$ things out of $N$ things?  In this case $N = {n \choose 2}$.

Comment: Is it maybe $$ \binom{\binom{n}{2}}{k}$$ ??

Comment: @MaryStar Yes it is!