# Cardinality of set of graphs with k indistinguishable edges and n distinguishable vertices

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

What is the cardinality of the set of [simple](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpleGraph.html), [connected](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConnectedGraph.html) graphs with k indistinguishable edges and n distinguishable vertices.

I've looked at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112954/how-many-non-isomorphic-graphs-with-n-vertices-and-m-edges-are-there) problem which is very similar, but not the same.

Examples:

2 edges, 3 vertices is 3

3 edges, 3 vertices is 1

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the answer is
$$\binom{\tfrac{1}{2}n(n-1)}{k}$$
if we drop the requirement of connectedness, right? For the connected case, I don't immediately see the general answer, but we do know some partial results. If $k<n-1$, then the answer is 0. If $k=n-1$, then the answer is $n^{n-2}$ by [Cayley's fomula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley's_formula). If $k>\frac{1}{2}n(n-1)-\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor\cdot\lceil\frac{n}{2}\rceil$, then the answer is
$$\binom{\tfrac{1}{2}n(n-1)}{k},$$
for then any graph with $n$ vertices and $k$ edges is necessarily connected.

Comment: I finally got back to this and wrote a python program to count this set. I will explain more formally in an answer later https://gist.github.com/SobiborTreblinka/e3e56465b3d4a18051428f04c4a32873

Comment: It seems that I was mistaken in my third special case. You need many more edges ($k > \frac{1}{2}n(n-1) - (n - 1)$, to be precise) to ensure that any graph with $n$ vertices and $k$ edges is connected. Not sure where the other formula came from... :P